Maximum Line Segments in an n × n Grid Without Loop formation
Exploring Proof for Maximum Line Segments in an (n * n) Grid Without Loop Formation
Hello Math SE community,
I am investigating how to maximize the number of line segments in an  $(n * n)$  grid without forming enclosed loops. Here, I provide definitions, examples, and illustrate optimal and non-optimal segment placements.
Definitions:

Grid: An $(n * n)$ matrix.
Line Segment: A straight segment that does not extend diagonally. It connects two points on the grid and is either completely vertical or horizontal.
Enclosed Loop: A region in the grid completely surrounded by segments with no gaps.

Correct vs. Incorrect Segment Placement:

Correct Placement: Segments that do not complete a loop.
Incorrect Placement: Segments that form a loop, enclosing an area.

Examples:
Example 1: Correct Placement
Correct Placement
Description: Grid with 2 vertical red lines and 1 horizontal blue line. No enclosed areas formed.
Example 2: Incorrect Placement (Loop Formation)
Incorrect Way
Description: Grid with vertical red lines and horizontal blue lines forming a loop, enclosing an area.
Optimal Strategy:
To maximize the number of line segments without forming enclosed loops, it is optimal to place as many vertical and horizontal lines as possible without completing a circuit. The following diagram shows an optimal strategy for a (4 * 4) grid:
Optimal Way
Description: All vertical and one horizontal line.
This configuration maximizes the number of segments without any loop formation, mine came N*(N+2) from the optimal approach. Could anyone provide feedback or suggest improvements to this approach?
Note: Just to clarify here each red line represents 4 line segments and the blue line 4 line segments.
Thank you in advance for your insights and help!

maximum "line segments" or maximum "broken lines " ?

Here Line segment is basically the four lines, surrounding the cell. You can also say broken lines. i hope this is better

Every tree graph with $n$ nodes has $n-1$ edges. Your grid has $(N+1)^2$ nodes, so if you connect them all without forming loops, you will always need $(N+1)^2-1 = N(N+2)$ edges. There is no optimal or non-optimal way to do it, they are all the same.

Thanks a lot @JaapScherphuis. I know that there is no optimal or non-optimal way to do it, just was looking for proof that my solution was correct for all N. Thanks for the proof. Could you maybe be a little more descriptive about the reasoning?

You can prove that every tree graph (connected graph without cycles) with $n$ nodes has $n-1$ edges by using induction. Here is one such proof. Then just substitute $n=(N+1)^2$ to apply it to this grid of nodes.
